# django connection to mongo and postgres

Tags: django, mongodb, postgresql, django-models

I need to connect to my web app in `django` to `mongodb` and `postgresql` to do CRUD operations on it, here is the code of the project that it´s on git hub.

[Here](https://github.com/defStacker/shop_Django/blob/master/untitled/settings.py) is the file where I made the connections to mongodb (isn´t working).

And [this](https://github.com/defStacker/shop_Django) is the link of the project

Answer (score 0):

Here is the info which might be useful to setup Mongo DB and PostgreSQL.

For Mongo DB connection setup,

```
DATABASES = {
  'default' : {
  'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
  'NAME' : 'my_database'
}}
```

For PostgreSQL connection setup,

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'your_project_name',
    'USER': 'project_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
}}
```

Connection setup must be added in settings.py file. Hope you know that.